# Fabric JS: How to Transform Fabric Image

Tags: html, canvas, javascript, fabricjs

How Can I skew and Scale left or right a Fabric Image inside a Canvas using Fabric JS?
I need it to follow the way this monitor is being displayed so I can paste it like it is 
being displayed on the screen

[image]

Comment: This should probably be possible with image filters, changing pixels in such way so that image appears skewed.

Answer (score 0):

Please go through [this](http://fabricjs.com/matrix-transformation/) link. You can set transform and skew as [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Rq7hk/26/)

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');



fabric.Image.fromURL("https://www.google.co.in/images/srpr/logo11w.png", function(img) {
    img.set({transformMatrix: [1, .30, 0, 1, 0, 0],width:200,height:50,top:100,left:150});
    img.setCoords();
    canvas.add(img);
    
    canvas.renderAll();
  })
```

```css
body {
    background-color: ivory;
    padding:30px;
}
canvas {
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<h3>FabricJS: using transformMatrix to skew-Y</h3>

<canvas id="canvas" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

Image transform in fabric js can be done using perspective js library
https://github.com/wanadev/perspective.js/

Below is the sample fabric js perspective image transform working example

https://kpomservices.com/ImageTransform/transform.html (double click on the image to view the drag handles)